# Ubuntu 16.04 installed on phone looks different

Tags: 16.04, phone

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an old phone (Nexus 5).

It seems to work but it doesn't look like the same version of Ubuntu I have on my laptop. Navbar is at bottom, name of console is 'LXTerminal'.. so I am a bit lost.

Is there a way to recover usual Ubuntu 16.04 appearance ?

Comment: Did you by any chance install [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) instead of the standard Ubuntu?

Comment: Well `lsb_release -a` says `no LSB modules are available - distributor if : Ubuntu - description : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS...` I have installed through Linux Deploy app.

Comment: Ohhh : desktop environment is LXDE. Didn't see that. Other options were XTerm Xfce MATE Other

Answer (score 0):

Unless your phone can handle it, and the option is available in Linux Deploy (last I remember it wasn't, the Unity DE), then no. Otherwise, try reinstalling the distro with the Unity DE.

Comment: I tried to install mate but it seemed to be worse. Then back to LXDE. Yet I couldn't install some programs.. then I have given up :) Well wasn't that useful on a small screen either. BAck to the laptop...

Comment: Have you tried the actual Ubuntu Touch OS (for mobile devices) instead? @Maxence https://ubuntu-touch.io/get-it